# Merge 2 Rails App subdirectories keeping git history

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, merge, git-history

I want to merge 2 Rails application "we can call *source*" into another Rails application "we can call *target*" distributed into subfolders without losing git history.

I want to merge only the main folders of rails.

**e.g.**

merge source/subfolder >> target/subfolder/source

merge source/subfolder/file.rb >> target/subfolder/source/file.rb

```
source
├── app
│   ├── controllers
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── helpers
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── jobs
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── mailers
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── models
│   │   └── ...
│   └── views
│       └── ...
├── config
│   └── ...
└── test
    └── ...
```

*target* app should look like:

```
target
├── app
│   ├── controllers
│   │   ├── source
│   │   │   └── ...
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── helpers
│   │   ├── source
│   │   │   └── ...
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── jobs
│   │   ├── source
│   │   │   └── ...
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── mailers
│   │   ├── source
│   │   │   └── ...
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── models
│   │   ├── source
│   │   │   └── ...
│   │   └── ...
│   └── views
│       ├── source
│       │   └── ...
│       └── ...
├── config
│   └── ...
└── test
    ├── source
    │   └── ...
    └── ...
```

I just want to keep the git history of the main subfolder, I will merge the rest of the files manually.

Following this post [here](https://jrsmith3.github.io/merging-a-subdirectory-from-another-repo-via-git-subtree.html), I have tried the git tool `git subtree` and it only works to merge an application "*source*" into a folder of the *target* like libraries or plugins, but I want to distribute subdirectories of the *source* app (controllers, models, helpers, views, specs, ...) into *target* app subdirectories.

The main objective of this is to can see in **Github** all the history of the files imported from *source* app into *target* app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**✅ [SOLUTION]**

Finally I found a solution very similar as [@matthewd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476979/matthewd) propose, Thanks [@matthewd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476979/matthewd).

What I did is prepare my *source* app to merge it directly to *target* app.

For each subfolder I wanted to merge, in source dir. I did :

```
in source/ $
```

1) Remove remote just to prevent remote changes.

```
$ git remote rm origin
```

2) Filter repo with the directory I want to merge (e.g. directory: app/controllers)

```
$ git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter <directory> -- --all
```

3) Prepare subfolder

```
$ mkdir target
$ mv * target
```

e.g. app/controllers/target

4) Add and commit the changes

```
$ git add --all
$ git commit -a -m "Controllers added"
```

Then:

```
in target/ $
```

1) I added the remote referenced to my local dir with the previous changes.

```
$ git remote add source <../target-dir>
```

1.1) Create a `branch` to work with.

```
$ git checkout -b new-branch
```

2) And `pull` the changes using `--allow-unrelated-histories` to my repo which if we created a correct subfolder should not have conflicts.

```
$ git pull source master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

And thats all, just `push` the changes to your current branch

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend following the merge-and-move strategy instead of subtree: to me, it keeps the history clearer (and unchanged).

1. Move the directories around in the source repository to produce the shape you want (deleting any files you don't want to bring across)
2. Commit that (on a temporary branch if you like)
3. Add the source repository as a remote in the target checkout
4. Merge the relevant branch from source into target, and commit
5. Apply any additional post-merge cleanup, connect the new parts together, etc.

There isn't really anything Rails-specific about that strategy, but as we're tagged for it, here's an example where I recently did the above: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/32097